# Libraries/Algorithms for complex if/else problems in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, rule-engine

I have to implement a questionnaire engine, where each answer to a single question can end up in a completely different result.

So, if we have 10 question with 10 answers each, we'd have a 10 to the power of 10 possibilities.

This should be something like a scripted-AI i guess...

So, what kind of rule engine or implementation method would I use for a problem like this?

I guess this kind of algorithm is a little bit too straightforward?

```
if (x==1)
  if (y==1)
  {
    if (z==1 || z==2)
      // do sth
    if (z==3)
      // do sth different
   }
```

Thanks for any advice on this.

Answer (score 4):

There are libraries that can be used to implement this form of "rules engine".

For example, [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx) allows basic rules to be determined via [FlowDecision activities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.activities.statements.flowdecision.aspx) and other related classes.

Other alternatives are rules engines, such as [Drools.Net](http://droolsdotnet.codehaus.org).

That being said, for simple routines like above, I'd recommend trying to refactor your algorithm to avoid lots of criteria.  By pushing this into multiple methods, you could create a series of clean conditions that would be much simpler to follow.